# Android list view boxed style

Tags: android, listview, styles

is it possible to edit the style of listview to resemble Google Currents app? It is a small white boxes on a gray background.

Something like here: http://www.shiftdigitalmedia.com/newsite/assets/google-now-5.png

Can you tell me how do I set the background for the list cell to achieve a similar result?

Comment: It certainly is possible. Simply use a 9-patch drawable for the background

Comment: This might be a good reference, too: http://nadavfima.com/cardsui-view-library/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved in many ways. Take a look at this for example: http://blog.donnfelker.com/2011/08/01/android-rounded-corners-with-a-beveldrop-shadow/

You can use an XML drawable, but beware, because it's not always the best option performance-wise, especially if shadows are involved.

Or you can use 9-patch drawables which are a little bit more tedious (you have to prepare them for different resolutions), but in many cases offer better performance.